# How to update with upsert option with Ruby Mongoid Moped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, moped

I need to update some data in the MongoDB if data already exists, if not to upsert or create record with  this data.
My models are:

```
class Garage 
  include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic


  has_many :cars
 end

class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  belongs_to :garage
  index({ car_make: 1, plate_number: 1  }, { sparse: true, unique: true, drop_dups: true })
 end
```

Then I have this query

```
 Garage.cars.collecttion.find(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234")
.update(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234", :car_colour=>"red", :year_make="2012", {upsert: true})
```

But this query does not add `Garage _id` to `cars` so it  does not work correctly.
I also tried another query:

```
Garage.cars.where(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234")
    .update(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234", :car_colour=>"red", :year_make="2012")
```

But it does not take `{upsert: true}` option, so it does not create a record if it does not exist yet!
Then I tried this:

```
Garage.cars.where(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234")
        .find_and_modify(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234", :car_colour=>"red", :year_make="2012", {upsert: true})
```

Geting error:

```
failed with error 11000: "exception: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key
```

Does anybody knows how to fix it? Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Garage.cars.where(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234").upsert(:car_make => "Ford", :plate_number =>"12x234", :car_colour=>"red", :year_make="2012")
```

Try this..not sure if this will work

Comment: Try to save the query object to a variable and then call the upsert on the saved object

Comment: I tried but it works very very slow, `Garage.cars.collection.find.... `works x100 times quicker but not assigning relations between `Garage and cars` Any ideas why? Anyway thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Need to check on that..might be because the count of objects in the collection is too big..